# Ghostscript PDF compression leads to "Output may be incorrect" errors

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, file-size

I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/535800) to compress PDFs generated from LaTeX. I run the commands:

```
 gswin64  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

On Windows and on *nix machines (i.e., macOs and Linux):

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

These commands used to work for all other PDF I have compressed so far. However, for a specific file I get a lot of errors:

> Ignoring spurious ET operator

,

> Executing Do inside a text block, attempting to recover

, and

> illegal nested BT operator detected.

all in the format of:

> **** Error:  ...  Output may be incorrect.

and then the output PDF is severely disfigured and corrupt. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what is wrong and how I can solve it.

**P.S.1.** I am using Ghostscript version `9.27` according to the command `gswin64  --version`

**P.S.2.** As a temporary solution, I printed the PDF into another PDF. I had two options on Windows, `Adobe PDF` and `Microsoft Print to PDF` and then run the commands above to further down-size the PDF file.

Comment: In your question you might want to note which version of ghostscript you are using as some are known to have errors

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the hint. I added the version in the **P.S.**

Comment: It is easy to add a spurious ET operator, but without a minimal example it is impossible to say why your latex code is doing it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischerAre you telling me it is possible to fix this issue from the LaTeX file? I can not put the whole paper here of course. But I'm using the `IEEEtran` and `ieeeconf.cls` if that's any help?

Comment: As I said: without a complete, small example it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would you be kind to give me any links where I can learn more about the `spurious ET operator`? I can't find anything relevant on the internet.

Comment: You can find the ET operator (and Do) in the pdf reference. But I doubt that this will help you - you still won't know why your pdf has the wrong syntax.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what PDF reference do you mean? my apologies, that I can't find it myself.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf